# Vue-Router add new route dynamically when there is a new component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I need to create a fully modular Vue project and I can't figure out how do I add or remove routes when there is a new component or a component is deleted.

Now I statically type all the routes that are available in my Sidebar menu. Let's say there are 10 menus in my sidebar, it means that I should type 10 routes in my routes.js file.

But I need this project to be modular. By saying modular what I mean is, I need to give the component list to the project, I think that I should do that with a .json file and let's say this file says that it has only 5 component available, then the related routes will be dynamically created in the routes.js file, and when one of them is deleted, the related route should be removed from the routes list as well. That is what I want.

I want to do that because I develop a single frontend with Vue for more than one device. These devices may have different options and menus, when the device and the frontend matches, only the available menus will be put in the sidebar, so I can't type all the routes statically as I've been doing the whole time.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through a list of routes and use the [`router.addRoute` function](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroute) to dynamically add them to your router instance (requires vue-router 3.5.0+), instead of loading them by default. You could do this from the `created()` hook of your main layout for example.

```
// app.vue

<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    created() {
      let routes = loadRoutes(); // insert your own function to get the correct routes here
      routes.forEach(route => this.$router.addRoute(route))
    },
  };
</script>
```

If you need to be able to switch between different layouts on the same device (like a shared terminal for managers and employees) you can reset the routes array by [creating a new router instance](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1234#issuecomment-357941465), or [removeRoute](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/dynamic-routing.html#removing-routes) (if you use v4.0+).